# LOCATE_IN_STRING Function in Db2

Tags: db2

Using `LOCATE_IN_STRING` function in `Db2` , I want to separate Field 2 & Field 3 from below string.

`RTN1319 5.7.18 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS`

Field 1 : Chk Number Field

Field 2 : Tr Date Field

Field 3 : Reason

I want to pull only TR Date & Reason

```
Select TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM('RTNCK1319 5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'),LOCATE_IN_STRING(TRIM('RTNCK1319 5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'),' ',+1))) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;


Select TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM('RTNCK1319 5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'),LOCATE_IN_STRING(TRIM('RTNCK1319 5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'),' ',+1))) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;
```

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` might be easier/provide more flexibility  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html

Answer (score 0):

For all Db2 for LUW versions:

```
with t (s) as (values 
  'RTNCK1319  5.7.19   INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'
)
select 
  xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:tokenize($s, " +")[2]' passing ltrim(t.s) as "s") as varchar(10))
, xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($s, "^ *[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +", "")' passing t.s as "s") as varchar(100))
from t;
```

---

Without regexp (1-st two intermediate spaces must be single):

```
with t (s) as (values 
  'RTNCK1319 5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS'
)
select 
  substr(s, s1pos+1, s2pos-s1pos) s1
, substr(s, s2pos+1) s2
from 
(
select 
  ltrim(s) s 
, locate_in_string(ltrim(s), ' ', 1, 1) s1pos
, locate_in_string(ltrim(s), ' ', 1, 2) s2pos
from t
);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply , I have tried this but now working as expected. I need output as below String1 = 5.7.19    String2 = INSUFFICIENT FUNDS

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Comment: Version : DB2 6.2.0.315 , I was getting output as "5.7.19 INSUFFICIENT FUNDS" as single string with the older query you suggested but I was expecting separate stings as 5.7.19   & INSUFFICIENT FUNDS. Thank you for all your help. :)

Comment: There is no such a db2 version on any platform: 6.2. Check the edited query in the answer. What's the result of `select * from sysibm.sysversions`?

Comment: Can you suggest with older approach only, instead of using xmlcast , Can we do this using LOCATE_IN_STRING & LOCATE function to split out two string referring to 1st & 2nd Delimiter.

Comment: Db2 version : VERSIONNUMBER VERSION_TIMESTAMP AUTHID VERSIONBUILDLEVEL
11010202 8/25/2017 5:00:40 PM PP1EDWI1 s1706091900

Comment: You use `Db2 for LUW 11.1.2.2`, not `6.2.0.315`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Thank you mark , Really appreciated your help on this.